# Call template function with one or two arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have situation when i create template function with one argument (component) and sometimes with two (component, gameObject).

```cpp
template<typename Component, typename F>
    static void CallFunction(GameObject gameObject, F func) {
        // Note: UIFunction should has component as first param and/or gameObject second.
        auto& component = gameObject.GetComponent<Component>();
        constexpr std::size_t args = sizeof...(F);
        if constexpr (args == 1)
            func(component);
        else
            func(component, gameObject);
    }
```

And i try to use `constexpr std::size_t args = sizeof...(F);` to get size of arguments of my function and call it with one argument or two. But when im try to use this i get:

`C2780   'auto CallFunction::<lambda_06a5858866216a23f9192bc2da910cdc>::operator ()(_T1 &,_T2) const': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided.`

How do this properly because im not big fan of templates.

Comment: How is this a variadic template?

Comment: I just don't know much about templates. Well, here I meant that a function in template can have one or more parameters to call.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use them then? Generally you have an overload case with either one or two very specific parameters, why do you need a variadic template at all?

Comment: I agree, but I just have another problem that I have a very large template function in my code
```<typename Component, typename F>
static void DrawComponent(const String& name, GameObject gameObject, F func) {
if (gameObject.GetComponent<Component>()) { ... call CallFunction  ... }``` and sometimes it need to pass one argument (component) and sometimes two. I just don't want to write second function like DrawComponent2 and write the same logic with only one argument difference.

Comment: And also because Component is actual template argument and GameObject not and i cannot use this without templates.

Comment: What do you expect from `sizeof...(F)`?

Comment: Im already fix that issue i remove `sizeof...(T)` and use 'std::is_invokable_v' for checking that func can be called with some count and type of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Im removed `sizeof...(T)` and use `std::is_invokable_v` for checking that func can be called with some count and type of arguments.

```cpp
template<typename Component, typename F>
    static void CallFunction(GameObject gameObject, F func) {
        // Note: UIFunction should has component as first param and/or gameObject second.
        auto& component = gameObject.GetComponent<Component>();
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Component>)
            func(component);
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Component, GameObject>)
            func(component, gameObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 type traits can be used to determine whether the object is invocable accepting some argument types. Small example, change it as needed:

```
template<typename> inline constexpr bool wrong_func_v = false;

template<typename Component, typename F>
static void CallFunction(GameObject gameObject, F func)
{
    auto& component = gameObject.GetComponent<Component>();
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Component>)
        func(component);
    else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Component, GameObject>)
        func(component, gameObject);
    else
        static_assert(wrong_func_v<F>, "wrong param types/count");
}
```

Then we can use this template:

```
CallFunction<SomeComponent>(gameObject, one_arg_func);
CallFunction<OrAnotherComponent>(gameObject, two_arg_func);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already figured it out.

Comment: Just didn't see your answer when posted.

Comment: Thanks anyway :)